# Unable to display data from api calls using v-for

Tags: vue.js

I want to display in a v-for list every categories of the https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php API.

When i do {{ categories }} i do have every info displayed but when i do {{ categories.strCategory }} i have a blank li.

here is my code

```html
<ul class="categorie-list">
            <li v-for="(categories, index) in categories" :key="index">
              {{ categories.strCategory }}
            </li>
          </ul>
```

```js
mounted() {
    this.getAllCategories()
  },
  data() {
    return {
      categories: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getAllCategories() {
      axios
        .get('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log( response.data);
          this.categories = response.data;  
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    },
```

i also get this alert in the console

```
[Vue warn]: Property "searchQuery" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <MainPage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted>
```

Comment: try changing naming convention to this `<li v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index"> {{ category.strCategory }}</li>`

Comment: it doesn't work :/

Comment: could you check console for errors and if found any update question with errors?

Comment: [Vue warn]: Property "searchQuery" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <MainPage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy {getAllCategories: ƒ, …} > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>

Comment: your question doesn't have `searchQuery` anywhere. Error might not be related to `category.strCategory`.

Comment: Edited it, ill try to find an answer and will but updating my question if i find it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248633/discussion-between-a-z-and-azciop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your point.

in Response you are getting array of object which has only one object so you need to assign response categories to local variable as per below mention.

working URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-gzxbkv?file=src/App.vue

```js
     methods: {
      getAllCategories() {
      axios
        .get('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data.categories);

          //before
          //this.categories = response.data;
          //after
          this.categories = response.data.categories;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
     },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you tried this:

```js
<ul class="categorie-list">
  <li v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index">
  //          ^^^^^^^^
    {{ category.strCategory }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it doesn't work :/